# C++ Programa se cae y no entiendo por qué

Tags: c++

Para mi tarea me dan el siguiente enunciado:

> Usted cuenta con una matriz de char declarada de la siguiente forma en
>   el .h e inicializada con dimensiones para las filas y las columnas en
>   el constructor:
>
> ```
> //En Matriz.h
>
> char ** m;
>
> //En Matriz.cpp
> //En constructor Matriz(int filas, int columnas)
> m = new char [filas][columnas];
> ```
>
> Especifique el método llamado **vocales()** que deje en la matriz solo el grupo más grande de vocales que sean vecinas entre sí dentro de la matriz, el resto de las
>   celdas deberán quedar con un blanco ' ', incluidos los grupos de
>   vocales más pequeños. Se consideran como vecinas a las ocho celdas que
>   la rodean. En caso de empate en la cantidad de vocales del grupo, se
>   dejará el primer grupo encontrado de arriba hacia abajo y de izquierda
>   a derecha, con esa cantidad de vocales conectadas.

Yo logré programar lo que me piden sin embargo el programa se cae y no entiendo por qué, si alguien se puede tomar el tiempo de ver el código y ayudarme se lo agradezco muchísimo, lo difícil de comprender está comentado.

```
//Matriz.h
#ifndef Matriz_H_TAREA_1
#define Matriz_H_TAREA_1
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

class Matriz{
    class Vocal;
    private:
        int f;
        int c;
        int contador;
        char ** m;
        vector< vector<Vocal> > vdv; //vdv significa Vector de Vectores
        vector<Vocal> comodin; //vector de objetos tipo Vocal vacío para usar de comodín.
        //void cargar(istream &);
        void vocalesRec(int, int);
        int esValida(int, int);
        int esVocal(int, int);
        class Vocal{
            private:
                int fila;
                int col;
                char letra;
            public:
                Vocal(int, int, char);
                ~Vocal();
                int getFila();
                int getCol();
                char getLetra();
        };
    public:
        Matriz(int, int);
        Matriz(char **, int, int);
        ~Matriz();
        void vocales();
        void imprimir();
};
#endif
```

-

```
//Matriz.cpp
#include "Matriz.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

//---------------Métodos clase Vocal-----------//
Matriz::Vocal::Vocal(int f, int c, char l){
    fila = f;
    col = c;
    letra = l;
}

Matriz::Vocal::~Vocal(){

}

int Matriz::Vocal::getFila(){
    return fila;
}

int Matriz::Vocal::getCol(){
    return col;
}

char Matriz::Vocal::getLetra(){
    return letra;
}
//-----------------------------------------------//

//--------------Métodos clase Matriz-------------//
Matriz::Matriz(int filas, int columnas){ //Inicializa las variables y crea una matriz de char
    f = filas;                          //y pone todos los valores en '\0'
    c = columnas;
    m = new char * [f];
    for(int i=0; i<f; ++i){
        m[i] = new char [c+i];
        for(int j=0; j<c+1; ++j){
            m[i][j] = '\0';
        }
    }
    //cout << f; //Esto sin comentar imprime el valor correcto en consola.
    contador = -1;
}

Matriz::Matriz(char ** matriz, int filas, int columnas){ //Constructor que recibe otra matriz de char
    Matriz(filas, columnas
    //cout << f; //Por alguna razón el valor cambia a algo muy extraño y por el programa muere.
    for(int i=0; i<filas; ++i){
        for(int j=0; j<columnas; ++j){ //Copia los valores de la otra matriz a esta.
            m[i][j] = matriz[i][j]; //Específicamente se muere al ejecutar esta linea.
        }
    }

}

Matriz::~Matriz(){ //Destructor
    for(int i=f; i>=0; --i){
        delete [] m[i];
    }
    delete [] m;
}

int Matriz::esValida(int fil, int col){ //Devuelve verdadero si una posicion es valida.
    return fil >= 0 && fil < f && col >= 0 && col < c;
}

void Matriz::vocales(){ 
    for(int i=0; i<f; ++i){ //Iterativamente recorre la matriz.
        for(int j=0; j<c; ++j){
            if(esVocal(i, j)){ //Si lo que hay en la posicion es una vocal
                contador++; //aumenta el contador
                vdv.push_back(comodin); //Le agrega un vector de objetos tipo Vocal al vector de vectores.
                vocalesRec(i, j); //Empieza a buscar los grupos de vocales.
            }
            else{

            }           
        }
    }

    int posMasGrande = -1;
    int tamMasGrande = -1;
    if(!vdv.empty()){ //Si el vector de vectores no está vacío, osea, se encontró por lo menos una vocal.
        for(int i=0; i<vdv.size(); ++i){//Revisa cada tamaño de cada vector
            if(vdv[i].size() > tamMasGrande){ //Cuando encuentra uno de mayor tamaño actualiza la variable.
                tamMasGrande = vdv[i].size();
                posMasGrande = i; //Indica en cual posicion del vector de vectores se encuentra el vector de Vocales de mayor tamaño.
            }
            else{

            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<f; ++i){ //Pone todos los valores de la matriz en espacios para también eliminar las consonantes.
            for(int j=0; j<c; ++j){
                m[i][j] = ' ';
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<vdv[posMasGrande].size(); ++i){ //Devuelve a la matriz las vocales del grupo más grande en sus posiciones correspondientes.
            m[vdv[posMasGrande][i].getFila()][vdv[posMasGrande][i].getCol()] = vdv[posMasGrande][i].getLetra();
        }
    }
    else{ //Si no había ninguna vocal se borra todo.
        for(int i=0; i<f; ++i){
            for(int j=0; j<c; ++j){
                m[i][j] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }
}

void Matriz::vocalesRec(int fil, int col){ //Busqueda de vocales recursivo.
    if(esValida(fil, col)){ //Solo se ejecuta si la posición ingresada es válida
        if(esVocal(fil, col)){ //Solo se ejecuta si lo que se encuentra en esa posicion es una vocal.
            vdv[contador].push_back(Vocal(fil, col, m[fil][col])); //Agrega una vocal al vector correspondiende en el vector de vectores.
            m[fil][col] = ' '; //Cambia lo que estaba ahí por un espacio
            vocalesRec(fil, col-1); //Revisa izquierda
            vocalesRec(fil-1, col-1); //Revisa arriba izquierda
            vocalesRec(fil-1, col); //Revisa arriba
            vocalesRec(fil-1, col+1); //Revisa arriba derecha
            vocalesRec(fil, col+1); //Revisa derecha
            vocalesRec(fil+1, col+1); //Revisa abajo derecha
            vocalesRec(fil+1, col); //Revisa abajo
            vocalesRec(fil+1, col-1); //Revisa abajo izquierda
        }
        else{

        }

    }
    else{

    }
}

int Matriz::esVocal(int fila, int columna){ //Devuelve verdadero si la letra en cierta posicion es una vocal.
    return ((m[fila][columna] == 'a') || (m[fila][columna] == 'e') || (m[fila][columna] == 'i') || (m[fila][columna] == 'o') || (m[fila][columna] == 'u'));

}

void Matriz::imprimir(){ //Muestra en la consola los componentes que hay en la matriz.
    for(int i=0; i<f;++i){
        for(int j=0; j<c;++j){
            cout << m[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
//-----------------------------------------------//
```

-

```
//main.cpp
#include "Matriz.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    char ** c = new char * [4]; //Se crea una matriz de char para suministralo luego.
    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i){
        c[i] = new char [4];
        for(int j=0; j<4; ++j){
            c[i][j] = '\0';
        }
    }
    c[0][0] = 'a'; //Se le asignan valores
    c[0][1] = 'e';
    c[0][2] = 't';
    c[0][3] = 'a';
    c[1][0] = 'i';
    c[1][1] = 'k';
    c[1][2] = 'p';
    c[1][3] = 'e';
    c[2][0] = 'o';
    c[2][1] = 'm';
    c[2][2] = 'n';
    c[2][3] = 'i';
    c[3][0] = 'u';
    c[3][1] = 'j';
    c[3][2] = 's';
    c[3][3] = 'o';

    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i){ //Se imprimen los valores de la matriz c.
        for(int j=0; j<4; ++j){
            cout << c[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


    Matriz * m = new Matriz(c, 4, 4); //Aqui se muere el programa.
    m->vocales();
    m->imprimir(); //Debería imprimir el grupo de aeiou

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola Marco, bienvenido a [es.so]. Tienes algun tipo de log? te da errores?

Comment: No, el programa compila sin ningún error.

Comment: Si, pero si se te *cae* es algun tipo de error en tiempo de ejecución. Lo corres en debug?

Comment: Apenas estoy aprendiendo como programar en c++ entonces no sé como usar un debug, sin embargo en el código comenté en cual línea es que se cae el programa.

Comment: ¿Puedes describir con detalle el concepto " **el programa se cae** " para que intentemos entender lo que te sucede?

Comment: Sale la típica ventanita de error. "vocales.exe ha dejado de funcionar". No sé como más explicarlo porque no entiendo porque deja de funcionar.

Comment: Tengo el `c++` bastante oxidado la verdad pero la primera línea del constructor al que invocas no está incompleta? `Matriz(filas, columnas` es un error tipográfico o me estoy perdiendo algo?

Comment: "*Sale el error. "vocales.exe ha dejado de funcionar"*". Seguramente ese error te permite depurar, lo cuál te mostrará la línea en que falla. Además en la salida del IDE y/o la de consola te deberían salir más detalles.

Comment: Si fue un error a la hora de copiar el código.

Answer (score 5):

```
Matriz::Matriz(char ** matriz, int filas, int columnas)
{ //Constructor que recibe otra matriz de char
  Matriz(filas, columnas); // (1)
  // ...
}
```

Tiene sentido, ambos constructores van a realizar la misma tarea y como sabes que no es bueno repetir código (o simplemente no te ha apetecido), decides reutilizar el constructor... la teoría está bien, no así la práctica. Lo que estás haciendo ahí es crear un objeto `Matriz` nuevo con una vida tan efímera que será destruído en cuanto el código abandone la línea (1). Quizás quedaría más claro así:

```
Matriz::Matriz(char ** matriz, int filas, int columnas)
{ //Constructor que recibe otra matriz de char
  Matriz matriz = Matriz(filas, columnas);
  // ...
}
```

Para reutilizar el constructor tendrías que realizar una llamada tal que:

```
Matriz::Matriz(char ** matriz, int filas, int columnas)
{ //Constructor que recibe otra matriz de char
  Matriz::Matriz matriz = Matriz(filas, columnas);
  // ...
}
```

Pero podrás comprobar que no funciona (y si te funciona no es un comportamiento admitido en el estándar de C++ así que ojo). ¿Cómo hacer entonces para no repetir código?  Solo te queda mover la funcionalidad a una función independiente:

```
class Matriz
{
  // ...

private:
  void Inicializar(int filas, int columnas);
};


void Matriz::Inicializar(int filas, int columnas)
{
  f = filas;
  c = columnas;
  m = new char * [f];
  for(int i=0; i<f; ++i){
    m[i] = new char [c]; // (1)
    for(int j=0; j<c; ++j){ // (2)
      m[i][j] = '\0';
    }
  }

  contador = -1;
}

Matriz::Matriz(int filas, int columnas){
  Inicializar(filas, columnas); 
}

Matriz::Matriz(char ** matriz, int filas, int columnas)
{
  Inicializar(filas, columnas);
  // ...
}
```

Ahora bien, si te fijas en la implementación de `Inicializar()` verás dos comentarios:

1. Cada fila de la matriz debería tener un número `c`de columnas, no `c+numero_de_fila`.
2. De acuerdo al punto anterior el bucle de inicialización también debería cambiar

Otro error que tienes se encuentra aquí:

```
Matriz::~Matriz(){ //Destructor
    for(int i=f; i>=0; --i){
        delete [] m[i];
    }
    delete [] m;
}
```

Cuando juegas a hacer los bucles al revés tienes que tener cuidado al invertir los límites del rango. El rango a liberar debería ser (f-1,0) y el que has implementado es (f,0). Como `m[f]` no existe el sistema operativo mata la aplicación.

Implementar los rangos de forma directa suele ser más sencillo y con menos errores:

```
Matriz::~Matriz(){ //Destructor
    for(int i=0; i<f; ++i){
        delete[] m[i];
    }
    delete[] m;
}
```

Y bueno, para rematar la faena vamos a revisar la función `vocalesRec`:

```
void Matriz::vocalesRec(int fil, int col){ //Busqueda de vocales recursivo.
    if(esValida(fil, col)){ //Solo se ejecuta si la posición ingresada es válida
        if(esVocal(fil, col)){ //Solo se ejecuta si lo que se encuentra en esa posicion es una vocal.
            vdv[contador].push_back(Vocal(fil, col, m[fil][col])); //Agrega una vocal al vector correspondiende en el vector de vectores.
            m[fil][col] = ' '; //Cambia lo que estaba ahí por un espacio
            vocalesRec(fil, col-1); //Revisa izquierda
            vocalesRec(fil-1, col-1); //Revisa arriba izquierda
            vocalesRec(fil-1, col); //Revisa arriba
            vocalesRec(fil-1, col+1); //Revisa arriba derecha
            vocalesRec(fil, col+1); //Revisa derecha
            vocalesRec(fil+1, col+1); //Revisa abajo derecha
            vocalesRec(fil+1, col); //Revisa abajo
            vocalesRec(fil+1, col-1); //Revisa abajo izquierda
```

Es decir, para cada posición intentas moverte de forma recursiva hacia las 8 adyacentes. Esto está condenado al fracaso porque el algoritmo no terminará nunca. Si empiezas en, por ejemplo, (0,0), el algoritmo podrá chequear (0,1) y de ahí volver a (0,0) y repetir el bucle indefinidamente. Tienes que tener mucho cuidado con las funciones recursivas para garantizar un final.

No veo en ninguna parte del enunciado que sea requisito implementar la función con recursividad así que yo me la ahorraría y programaría la función con bucles, que son más sencillos de depurar y de entender. En esta función no me meto porque ese es, según el enunciado, el ejercicio que tienes que realizar.